# Data download from PHP is not split into newlines

Tags: vb.net, string, newline, split

I am retrieving data from web. Data is seperated by each line. Data looks like this

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

I want to alert for each data found on the webpage. Tried this,

```
    Dim Lines() As String
    Dim stringSeparators() As String = {vbCrLf}
    Dim Source As String
    Dim wc As New WebClient

    Source = wc.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/data.php")
    Lines = Source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None)
    For Each s As String In Lines
        MsgBox(s)
    Next
```

But unfortunately, it alerts once all the data. My question is, how to alert for each data ?

Comment: What is the *actual* EOL character(s)? It is probably "just" a newline or `\n`, which is the line ending on every other mainstream OS except for windows..

Comment: @user198989: fyi, i've deleted my anser since i've overlooked that `stringSeparators` is already a `String()` and not a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vbCrLf`, as [defined in Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants_fields(v=vs.110).aspx), won't match a single [UNIX-style newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) - "Newline" (`\n`), [LF/LINEFEED, ASCII 10](http://www.asciitable.com/) - character as transmitted from PHP.

To deal with *both* Windows and UNIX/Linux end-of-line sequences, use:

```
Dim stringSeparators() As String = {vbLf, vbCrLf}
```

The order the separators supplied does not matter, see the remarks in [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

While the above solves the problem in a fairly robust manner, it *may* better to use the *exact* EOL format, especially when writing - and to make a selection prior based on established format. In this case that might be only using `vbLf` which would work for the given PHP output, but would incorrectly leave in CR characters for Windows text files.

When dealing with system-native text files, or Windows components such as Controls, `vbNewLine` should generally be preferred over `vbCrLf`: `vbCrlLf` is appropriate when the goal is to be *explicit*, as above, and only accept/emit a specific ASCII sequence as mandated by protocols and conventions.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with whitespace characters, I often end up running the String.Asc() method on them, to see what they really are.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.asc(v=vs.110).aspx

Then, you can ensure that you are splitting on the correct character.